# Access app by face recognition

Tags: java, android, android-studio, face-recognition

I'm trying to make an app which will check the face of the user by using the front camera the first time it is launched and then save how that face looks.

After that, every time someone starts the app it will check if his or her face is similar to the one that the app saved on its first launch, and if it's similar, proceed, if not, quit.

I know that there is face recognition unlock for Android, so I hope it's possible.

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318517/face-recognition-library-in-android)?

Comment: this way seems pretty hard, so i'm thinking about taking pictures and then compare them.
i mean take one on first launch and save it  and on every other launch take another one and compare with the first one, what do you say?
and what about these:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Face.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.Face.html
can these help me?